# Salesforce and Customer Flow management hardware - any experience?

Tags: app

I know Salesforce API can be leveraged for this but I wondered if anyone has any experience with apps/products that could save my organization some time.

Essentially the Customer Services will require a physical machine to grant customers a ticket number, when the ticket number is called they go to an agent and their issue/product etc is discussed. I was wondering if there is any solution out there that integrate with Salesforce (natively?)?

In my research I've found a bunch of suppliers but they all charge quite a lot for a whole heap of functionality that we don't required. (some offers salesforce integration but always at an extra cost).  We are really after simple physical ticket production and then relate that ticket to a salesforce case/call without many bells and whistles.

Thanks,

Comment: It's technically possible to do this relatively easy with something like a Raspberry Pi and a competent developer, but I'm not aware of any out-of-the-box solutions.